# Color Scheme on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, meta

The second question should have a different color since I favorited 'tags'. While the RGB values I picked from the picture try to convince me of a difference between the background of the second question I can honestly not see it (I am a bit red-green color blind). Can we get something that looks actually a bit different for the 5% with a color deficiency?

[image]

Comment: Here's a feature I didn't know about. Looking at the code, the background of the tagged question is a light gray #fafafb. The background of other list items is transparent -- i.e., you can see the page's background pattern. Because the background pattern is also a light gray, they are virtually indistinguishable.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146005/can-the-meta-sites-have-non-color-based-visual-cues-to-help-distinguish-them-fro

Answer (score 3):

The background color of page elements marked `tagged-interesting` should be changed from the color `#fafafb`. That color is basically indistinguishable from the default background. It should be darkened. The color `#eff0f1`, which is already in the scheme for code blocks and blockquotes, would do fine.

I have flagged this as a bug. The site design clearly intends questions marked `tagged-interesting` to have a contrasting color. This is a problem in implementation, i.e., a bug. Probably easily squashed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell the difference in the original screenshot and I have regular color vision. However, things have changed since then and I can now see the highlight for followed tags. Looking at color blindness simulators, I can even see the difference in monochrome, though it's subtle. There's also now an eyeball on any tags that you're following for an additional visual cue.

Regular:

[image: pale yellow background]

Greyscale:

[image: very light grey background]